# Achievements badge icon partially obscured

Tags: bug, design, achievements-dialog

If you look closely, you'll notice that the stackoverflow "dot" icon is partially covered by the white background of the text, giving it a "flat" righthand side. There's an alignment issue there.

[image]

I know that this is about as minor as bugs get, but someone may want to know.

---

FYI: Problem found on Windows 7, Chrome.

AFAICT only SO has this problem, hence posting here instead of meta.SE

Comment: That circle is... too circly :). (I can't reproduce that on Firefox 49.0.2, but maybe because the achievement was a couple of days ago?).

Comment: Are you running any user scripts? I cannot reproduce this in win7 chrome.

Comment: Try pressing CTRL+minus sign and reload. I was able to reproduce with zoom of 110%. (with 100% it is fine)

Comment: @Travis Not running scripts, but I do have the "SE auto" extension, but even with that off I get the problem

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I can confirm that as well.

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: @Will "Uneasy" is a better word - yes. Every time I see something like that I cringe. The most common example is misaligned, round manhole covers (where there's an alignable pattern). I'm curious - what's "wrong" with the gas pump display? Is it the decimal points don't align?

Comment: The gas pump has a perfectly round number in the bottom and is only one cent off from being perfect on the top.  That's enough to set off some people, I guess.  I expect that kind of person is pumping their gas, watching the numbers go up, sees that they are going to converge, plans to stop pumping just before reaching perfection, then gives the handle short shots to creep up juuuust until... they stop one cent off because they're trolling the crap out of everybody watching.

Comment: @Will but gas, and many other things, are usually priced just under a round number, eg $399.9 cents per gallon, because most humans lack the math plugin which would allow them to see 399.9 as a close approximation to 400, so they *truncate* it mentally to $3/gal and feel like they're getting a good deal. 10 gal @ 399.9 cents / gal = $39.99 (I have the plugin)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to page zoom.

Chrome, for good and for bad, keeps the last zoom setting for each page. Probably at some point you changed the zoom to 110% by mistake, closed the tab/browser, and moved on.

To confirm that, take a look in the right end of the address bar:

[image]

If you see this icon, it means there is a zoom. Just put it back to 100% and all will be good again. :)

Comment: I have 100% zoom. I'll add a screenshot with the zoom displayed. Oh, and I don't see that magnifying glass icon.

Comment: Actually... this is weird. It is happening on *some* pages *some* of the time (all with 100% zoom). I'm investigating further to figure it out how to reproduce reliably.

Comment: @Bohemian ping me if you can reproduce, as I cannot.  Thanks!

Comment: @Bohemian might also be local caching, storing old version of the CSS. Try clearing cache (usually CTRL+F5) and see. If still no luck, Inspect the element, it should have `badge3` class and such style: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao2HN.png so if you see something else (e.g. -60px) it means wrong style sheet is somehow loaded.